# Unnatural pause in Spanish neural voices

Tags: azure, text-to-speech, azure-cognitive-services

The Spanish neural voices narrate differently and make pauses that they did not make before.
As I understand it, TTS is designed to cut sentences of more than 300 phonemes with a pause, and that worked fine a month ago with Jorge Mexico's voice, but for several weeks now using a 300-phoneme sentence it makes an unwanted pause around 170 phonemes, making the narration sound unnatural.  It should be noted that I have been using TTS since the beginning of this year and this was not happening before, but for about a month now this problem has been occurring.

I did a test using a long text without commas using another voice which is the voice of Yago Mexico, and this one effectively cuts around 300 phonemes, while the voice of Jorge Mexico (which is the one I use) cuts around 170 phonemes. Using the same text.

SSML:

```
<!--ID=B7267351-473F-409D-9765-754A8EBCDE05;Version=1|{"VoiceNameToIdMapItems":[{"Id":"ace72e9b-dd48-4374-b508-39af2d140d16","Name":"Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (es-MX, JorgeNeural)","ShortName":"es-MX-JorgeNeural","Locale":"es-MX","VoiceType":"StandardVoice"}]}-->
<!--ID=FCB40C2B-1F9F-4C26-B1A1-CF8E67BE07D1;Version=1|{"Files":{}}-->
<!--ID=5B95B1CC-2C7B-494F-B746-CF22A0E779B7;Version=1|{"Locales":{"es-PE":{"AutoApplyCustomLexiconFiles":[{}]},"es-MX":{"AutoApplyCustomLexiconFiles":[{}]}}}-->
<speak xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xmlns:mstts="http://www.w3.org/2001/mstts" xmlns:emo="http://www.w3.org/2009/10/emotionml" version="1.0" xml:lang="es-MX"><voice name="es-MX-JorgeNeural">Ante esto el gato se asusta y eriza su cola para preguntarle si acaso eso no era gratis, a lo que Seyun le responde que lamentablemente no existe nada gratis en este mundo y justo ahí  se aprecia como los demás empiezan a rodearlo para que no intente escapar sin pagar además de que no esperaban al blanco acercarse para comer una rica comida junto a ellos en la gran mesa del salon.</voice></speak>
```

The pause occurs in the word blanco. I reiterate that using the same text with other voices such as Yago MX does not produce this unwanted pause.

Comment: Can you provide more details in the question, please edit with your code and what you have tried then will help you.

Comment: @DasariKamali Forgive me if I have not explained myself well, I do not speak English. I have already edited it.

Comment: Have you tried any code for this, if yes please provide it.

Comment: @DasariKamali  If you are referring to the SSML, I have already put it.

Comment: Why the Google Drive link? Text can be pasted in a question...

Comment: @MrUpsidown Sorry I didn't know how to put it, now I did it.